# how to knit in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, pandoc

I had to reinstall rstudio for some reason and now it just wont knit, everything is correct (even if I just try to knit the demo version.) I keep getting this error and have no idea what to do:

```
sh: /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc: Bad CPU type in executable
Error in strsplit(info, "\n")[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
Calls: <Anonymous> ... pandoc_available -> find_pandoc -> lapply -> FUN -> get_pandoc_version
In addition: Warning message:
In system(paste(shQuote(path), "--version"), intern = TRUE) :
  running command ''/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc' --version' had status 126
Execution halted
```

Comment: You appear to be on a Mac, and have installed executables for the wrong architecture.  Uninstall it and try again. (RStudio only offers one download option, but it appears to have chosen to install the wrong files.  Hopefully they've fixed that by now, or if it was your fault, you'll do it correctly next time.)

Comment: I already tried unistalling but I still get the same error

Comment: In that case there's a bug in what you installed.  You are trying to run a version of Pandoc that does not run on your computer.  This might be the one included with RStudio, or you might have another one on your system that it is finding first.  You can use `rmarkdown::find_pandoc()` to see where RStudio is finding Pandoc.  If that's somewhere in `/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources` it looks like an RStudio bug.  If it's somewhere else on your system, just delete it and things should work.

Comment: yes it is in there: > rmarkdown::find_pandoc()
sh: /Applications/RStudio 3.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools/pandoc: What should I do then?

Comment: Some tools don't like having spaces in their paths.  Maybe rename "RStudio 3.app" to "RStudio3.app".  But there's something else going on too:  the error message lists a different path.